# What size jet engines would it take to make a Cessna 140 hover?

Tags: jet-engine, aircraft-performance, hover, stol

I'm building a STOL bush plane using 4 jet engines located at 4 different points on the aircraft. I would like to know what size jet engines it would take to hover something like a [Cessna 140](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_140).

Comment: You just need more thrust than it weighs. How much is it going to weigh? Maybe 2x the weight would do it.  And what happens if one of the engines flames out, or ingests a little bird or something? The engines will make a C140 a lot heavier, which means more thrust, which means heavier engines, which means more thrust needed, which means heavier engines, which means more fuel needed, which means more thrust needed, which means heavier engines, oops still more fuel needed. Eventually you end up with something that is very safe because it can't get off the ground.

Comment: Jet engine or rocket engine? Assuming the latter, do you have a supplier lined up?

Comment: Everyone’s been ignoring the most obvious problem with this. Jet exhaust at high temperatures, creates a forest or brush fire hazard associated with the operation of this aircraft.

Comment: @CarloFelicione although there have been multiple implementations of this concept: The F-35, the Harrier, numerous development constructs like the "Schwebegestell" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VFW_SG_1262_Schwebegestell

Comment: Ah, but @U_flow your examples take off from improved, paved (or metal) runways. A "bush plane" (as the OP is planning on) will take off from unimproved grass/weed runways that, if not dry before the take off/landing attempt will rapidly become so at the exhaust temps of a jet engine, then quickly start burning.

Comment: @FreeMan The Harrier at least tried operating off grass and pierced metal planking - rather than fire the primary issue appears to have been more carving trenches into the surface that impacted safe landing and FOD issues to everything nearby. Though in the right (not damp UK?) conditions I'm sure something like this could first lightly toast the grass alight, then launch it afire across a wide area for optimal 'not get invited back' points.

Comment: Interesting, @GremlinWranger. Hadn't thought about it being an effective tool for bringing back trench warfare, but that does make sense, too.

Answer (score 6):

The AV-8B has a maximum thrust of 23,500 lbf for a VTOL MTOW of 20,750 lbs.
For a plane the weight of the Cessna 140, which weighs 1450 lbs loaded, you'd need total thrust of about 1640 lbf. So 410 lbf each.

The excess thrust (TWR of 1.13) was needed to enable for a transition from hover to flight by rotating the nozzles. If you only use jets for hover, and retain a propeller and an engine for forward thrust, you'd be able to use a total thrust equal to total weight, a TWR of 1.

A modern plane that size can weigh less than the Cessna 140, [as little as 1040 lbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%26F_Fk14_Polaris). However, the engines will add 40 lbs each, not counting the need to carry two types of fuel if the main engine is an avgas piston, so you're at a minimum of 1200 lbs loaded.

The best new-build engine for your requirements is probably the PBS [TJ150](https://www.pbs.cz/en/Aerospace/Aircraft-Engines/Jet-Engine-PBS-TJ150), although I can't be sure about cost and availability.
A less-advanced option is the [AMT Lynx](https://amtjets.com/lynx.php), which offers 350 lbf of thrust, but has worse fuel economy. It is meant for hobby and experimental designs though, and can be ordered for ~$55k per unit.

Overall, lift jets are an expensive way to get VTOL capability, but it's your project. Four engines will also burn 4-5 gallons per minute of hover, so account for that in the design. Rapid transition to horizontal flight and lift will minimize the fuel burn.

In general, jets are not a practical or safe option for a bush plane, since they produce heat and kick up ground debris, which can damage the engines themselves. It's safer and more fuel-efficient to spread power over more air, using propellers or rotors.

Answer (score 2):

#### How many engines do you want to use?

In each VTOL, weight is key! As each engine you have to lift means, more duplicate weight (housing, fuel systems, starter etc.) it follows that you want **as few engines as possible!!!** This is also the reason why all jet-powered aircrafts have only one jet engine. In the following, I assume that you only install one jet. Last but not least, there simply are no jets (at least as far as I know) small enough such that you could install four of them. Either they weight more then your structure can handle or they produce far to much thrust.

#### Which engine do you need?

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_140), the gross weight of a Cessna 140 is about 658 Kg. Given that most VTOL aircraft have a thrust to weight ratio of about 1.1 to 1.3 you need a minimum of $1.1 \cdot 658 Kg = 724 Kg$ of thrust + the engine weight. Again, a quick look on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_turbofan_manufacturers#Commercial_turbofans_in_production) gives a nice table of engines from which I chose the [PW530](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_Canada_PW500#Specifications) with a weight of [280Kg](https://www.easa.europa.eu/en/downloads/7715/en) and a thrust of around 12,84kN resulting in a lift to weight ratio of around $1284/(658+280)=1.37$ which should be enough also for the needed additional control system, fuel, cabeling etc.

Note that from that table, you see two things: This is one of the absolute smallest jet engine out there. There are other engines with less thrust (around 6kN) but they weight around 170Kg. Therefore when you had 4 of these, the engines would weight more then your aircraft. This means that a single engine is the weight-optimal (and cost optimal) way for such an aircraft.

#### Is it feasible to build a VTOL Cessna with Jet-engines?

No

##### Why?

Availability, cost, certification.

Answer (score 2):

Making a VTOL Cessna 140 might be possible, but you'd probably end up needing to get a Supplemental Type Certificate if you intend to use the aircraft afterwards.

Firstly, the Continental O-190 engine that is usually installed on Cessna 140s runs on avgas, which means that you'd need to replace the engine with something like a [CD-135 turbo-diesel engine](http://continentaldiesel.com/typo3/index.php?id=65&L=1) if you intend to use one fuel tank for both the main engine and the lift jets. This engine does have the advantage of giving you 50 extra horsepower, but it also weighs 53 kilograms (115.4 lbs) more than the O-190.

Assuming that you find a CD-135 engine and install it, your Cessna 140 will have an empty weight of 457 kilograms (1,004.3 lbs). This rises to 533 kilograms (1,171.35 lbs) with 25 gallons of Jet-A fuel, since Jet-A is slightly heavier than Avgas. In order to achieve a TWR of 1 with 4 lift-jets, each lift-jet needs to produce roughly 295 lbf of thrust. In this case you'd probably need to use the [PBS TJ150 turbojet](https://www.pbsaerospace.com/aerospace-products/engines/turbojet-engines/tj-100-turbojet-engine-1), which weighs 37.7 lbs, and produces 337 lbf of thrust. Since you'll be using 4 of these engines, the Cessna 140 contraption will end up weighing 608.6 kilograms (1344.15 lbs). Conveniently enough, the 4 TJ150 engines will produce 1,348 lbf of thrust. This technically does mean that your Cessna 140 contraption will have a TWR above 1, but you wouldn't really be able to hover around in it since it would only take 4 pounds of additional weight to cause the TWR to fall below 1.

Secondly, even if you managed to shave off enough weight from the airframe so that you could actually get on the Cessna 140 contraption without causing the TWR to fall below 1, you'd need to find some way to control the aircraft while it's hovering, since control surfaces don't work while the aircraft isn't moving. [Aircraft like the Harrier jump jet divert some of their engine's thrust to reaction control nozzles in order to provide pitch and roll authority during vertical flight](https://web.archive.org/web/20111014143000/http://www.centennialofflight.gov/essay/Theories_of_Flight/control/TH28G9.htm) but that wouldn't be possible in this case. You might be able to attach the turbojets to servo motors so that you could swivel them in order to get some degree of pitch and roll authority during vertical flight but this would only make the contraption even heavier.

Comment: Jet engines can run on avgas.  It makes them need maintenance more frequently, but they _can_ do it.

Comment: True, turbines will run on literally any flammable liquid, but given that this contraption needs four of them and losing even one lift-jet would be enough to render the contraption unflyable, it's probably a good idea to just stick with what the manufacturer says the turbine is supposed to run on.

Comment: Controlling a quad-lift vehicle is actually very simple - a basic feedback from 6-axis gyro to a 2x2 matrix. That's how consumer drones work. Square-arrangement quadcopter is a very stable configuration. 

The Harrier couldn't control nozzles one by one, it was manual, but still ran easily. The F-35B with its Y-arrangement would've been an instant crash without FBW.

Comment: Quadcopters are indeed very stable, **as long as all four motors are working.** Lose one motor and the quadcopter becomes a lawn mower.